# Updating a JavaScript object property

Tags: javascript, object, methods

```js
 function person(f, l) {
     this.firstName = f;
     this.lastName = l;
     this.changeName = function (str) {
     this.lastName = str; }
     this.getInitials = function() {
         {return f[0] + l[0]} }}
 
 var foo = new person("Joe","Smith"); 
 foo.changeName("Brown");
 alert(foo.firstName + " " + foo.lastName);
 alert(foo.getInitials())
```

The first `alert()` gives what I'd expect it to, namely "Joe Brown".  However, the second one gives 'JS'.

What is going on here?  If `foo.lastName` if now "Brown" shouldn't it show `JB` rather than `JS`?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
this.getInitials = function() {
    {return f[0] + l[0]}
}
```

To:

```
this.getInitials = function() {
    return this.firstName[0] + this.lastName[0];
}
```

You're returning the first letters of the parameters passed to `Person` (`f`/`l`), instead of the actual variables that store the (new) names (`this.firstName`/`this.lastName`).

Also, the extra `{}` block that wrapped the `return` makes no sense. I removed it.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
function person(f, l) {
    this.firstName = f;
    this.lastName = l;
    this.changeName = function (str) {
        this.lastName = str;
    }
    this.getInitials = function() {
        return this.firstName[0] + this.lastName[0];
    }
}

var foo = new person("Joe","Smith"); 
foo.changeName("Brown");

alert(foo.firstName + " " + foo.lastName);
alert(foo.getInitials())
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function person(f, l) {
      this.firstName = f;
      this.lastName = l;
      this.changeName = function(str) {
        this.lastName = str;
      }
      this.getInitials = function() {
        //problem here, you are showing variables that initialize class
        //return f[0] + l[0];
        //changeName doesn't affect argument variables, only class vars
        //so you have to use class vars in this func
        return this.firstName[0] + this.lastName[0];
      }
    }

    var foo = new person("Joe", "Smith");
    foo.changeName("Brown");
    alert(foo.firstName + " " + foo.lastName);
    alert(foo.getInitials())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are actually getting the original value that you input for the arguments "f" and "l".  When you access the method `this.getInitials`, you want to use `this.firstName` and `this.lastName` rather than f and l.

So your method should be `{return this.firstName[0] + this.lastName[0]}` in order for them to update properly.

Comment: `getInitials` is a getter. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Sorry, original comment was unclear.  I meant to say he's getting the original values 'f' and 'l' (which aren't changed by changeName) rather than the updated values.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `this.lastName` and `this.firstName`:

```
this.getInitials = function() {
  {
    return this.firstName[0] + this.lastName[0]
  }
}
```